# How do I get exempted from property taxes in India for lack of basic civic facilities?

Tags: income-tax, india, real-estate, state-income-tax, property-taxes

My property comes under panchayat administration and I have been paying my property taxes for the past 5 years but since time immemorial no basic facilities like road, drainage and street light at least has been provided by the administration. Is there anyway I could get an exemption from paying property taxes till the time I get those basic civic facilities?

Comment: Generally in such democracies you vote for someone else who will promise to provide such facilities if you're dissatisfied with the current administration.

Comment: Are you not allowed to build your own road and install your own lights, or just not able to afford to do so?

Comment: @RobertLongson That's not the only way. In the US, if you're unsatisfied with the services provided by the city/township, there are procedures to leave the city (_deannexation_). You would no longer be subject to property and sales taxes imposed by the city, and services like roads and street lighting would revert to the county. The group would also be free to form their own city.